# Getting an odd error trying to compile a Python Executable

Tags: python, pandas, executable, py2exe, keyerror

I'm attempting to use Py2exe to create a Python executable out of my program. The program definitely works and I've made sure all the libraries it uses are up to date, but when I attempt to run the command "python setup.py py2exe" to finish it up, I get an error I'm unfamiliar with.

The full output is below:
running py2exe
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\intern\pdf\setup.py", line 11, in 
setup(console=[{ "script": "tca_script.py"}],
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 192, in run
self._run()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 272, in _run
builder.analyze()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 172, in analyze
mf.import_package(modname)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 84, in import_package
self.import_package("%s.%s" % (name, modname))
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 84, in import_package
self.import_package("%s.%s" % (name, modname))
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 84, in import_package
self.import_package("%s.%s" % (name, modname))
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 71, in import_package
package = self.modules[name]
KeyError: 'pandas.tests.io.excel'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.